# How can I connect singleton class signals to mainwindow class slot or method

Tags: c++, qt

I own a serial communication class and I want to send a signal when I receive a commend because the data reception is over. As a result of this signal, I'm calling a graphical method. The connection is established, but the receiving slot does not listen to the signal.

singleton class:

```
class SerialCommunication : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT public:
static SerialCommunication  &   GetInstance()                                                               ;
....

QVector<double>                 ReadDataVector                                                              ;
```

private:

```
SerialCommunication()                                                                                       ;
static SerialCommunication  *   Instance                                                                    ;
QList<QSerialPortInfo>          PortList                                                                    ;
bool                            IsOpen          =   false   ; ....
```

private slots:
     void                           ReceivedData()                                                              ;

signals:
     void                           DataIsDone()                                                                ;

};

ReceivedData slot :

```
void SerialCommunication::ReceivedData()
```

{
    ...

```
for(;true;)
{
    ....
    switch (Commend) {
    case Data_Reply:
        qDebug()<<"Data Reply" ;
        AppendToUint16Vector(ReadDataVector,Package);
       break;
    case Data_Reply_Done:
        qDebug()<<" Data_Reply_Done" ;
        MsgBox.information(0,"Transfer information. ","The data transfer is complete \n Please click draw button.");
        emit SerialCommunication::GetInstance().DataIsDone();
       break;
   default:
        ClearBuffer();
        qDebug()<<" default" ;
       break;
    }}}
```

and connection is here

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(&SerialCommunication::GetInstance(),SIGNAL(SerialCommunication::DataIsDone),this,SLOT( GraficSetupAndInit()));
    SetupUI();

}
```

QObject::connect: Parentheses expected, signal SerialCommunication::SerialCommunication::DataIsDone in ..\Muteferrika\MainWindow.cpp:10
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the old `Qt4` syntax your `connect` call should be...

```
connect(&SerialCommunication::GetInstance(), SIGNAL(DataIsDone()),
        this, SLOT(GraficSetupAndInit()));
```

Having said that you really should be using the newer [signal-slot syntax](http://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) available with `Qt5`.  Specifically...

```
connect(&SerialCommunication::GetInstance(), &SerialCommunication::DataIsDone,
        this, &MainWindow::GraficSetupAndInit);
```